# Custom sorting using script in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make use of the scripting to sort the results in the elasticsearch with custom logic. I have read the docs from the elasticsearch and could not make it up. After seeing some links on the internet, I tried a bit and below is the source code for the same. I am using native (Java) for it. I am not sure whether this is the correct approach.

```
import org.elasticsearch.script.ExecutableScript;
import org.elasticsearch.script.NativeScriptFactory;
import customSortProject.Sorted;

import java.util.Map;

public class CustomScriptFactory implements NativeScriptFactory {

    public ExecutableScript newScript(Map<String, Object> params) {
        return new Sorted(params);
    }

}
```

And the class where i am implementing the logic for the sore. Currently I am just getting the future dates.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.elasticsearch.common.Nullable;
import org.elasticsearch.script.AbstractSearchScript;


public class Sorted extends AbstractSearchScript {
      String fieldParam;
      int lengthParam;

      public Sorted(@Nullable Map<String,Object> params){
          fieldParam = (String)params.get("field");
        lengthParam = new Integer(params.get("length").toString()).intValue();
      }
    public Object run() {
        if(source().containsKey(fieldParam) && source().get(fieldParam)!= null && source().get(fieldParam).toString() != null) { 


            String field = doc().get(fieldParam).toString();
            field = field.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
            long fieldLong = 0;
            Date today = new Date();
            fieldLong = Long.parseLong(field);          
            Date date = new Date(fieldLong);
            List<Date> futureList = new ArrayList<Date>();
            if (date.after(today))
                futureList.add(date);

            Collections.sort(futureList);

            return futureList;

          }
          else {           
            return "";
          }
    }

}
```

With this logic and using the query_dsl where I am trying to call this script which is register in .yml file.

Query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "cancer"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "sorted",
      "lang": "native",
      "type": "string",
      "ignore_unmapped": true,
      "params": {
        "field": "startdate",
        "length": 6
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know is this correct approach to custom sorting. I want to call it from the query dsl, as our application is in PHP and we are using PHP's es-client to search.